# Hot to get the value of the current selected element in taiko test?

Tags: javascript, html, gauge

In my taiko test script I selected an input element with the proximity parameter.
Then I can write some text in the input element.
After that, I want to make an assertion, that the text was actually written into that element by checking the value. How do I do that?

Here is an excerpt of my test script:

```
await click($(`input`, below('someHeader')));
await write('abc');
```

The input field has no id.
How can I write a check, that the value is 'abc' ?

Answer (score 0):

`textBox` is the selector that represents all text inputField in Taiko...
proximity selector can be used to fetch the inputfield to write and get its value like below

```
await write('abc',into(textBox(below('someHeader'))));
await textBox(below('someHeader')).value();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text stored by using any [selectors](https://docs.taiko.dev/api/reference/). If there is no any ID then you can try using label name, textBox or you can try using xpath

```
const myText = await $("xpath_value").text();
assert.strictEqual(myText, 'abc')
```